# Tomcat Valve settings

Tags: java, configuration, tomcat

I'm stuck with sort of a configuration issue I think. I need to protect
a folder which is within my actual tomcat application from access from
a certain IP range.

I thought this was [serverfault](http://serverfault.com), so I posted the question [there](https://serverfault.com/questions/90533/tomcat-6-ip-restrictions).
Right now I'm not sure whether this is SO or SF anyways...

Nevertheless I kept on trying geting it going  by myself and figured that
I need to set the

```
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve
```

for that folder of mine. Sadly I just can't get where I need to make that
setting. web.xml, server.xml ? Tried both, null success. Could anyone pls
help me out on this.

tia

K

Comment: I've added a section about filters to my answer.  I think this is what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should go inside your `<Context>` element in server.xml:

```
<Context
    path="/tcadmin"
    docBase="${catalina.home}/server/webapps/admin"
    privileged="true"
>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
        allow="127\.0\.0\.1"
    />
</Context>
```

Just remember, that the string values are regex patterns, so special regex characters ( e.g. dot(.) ) has to be escaped with backslashes.

**EDIT**: in reply to OP's comment.
I think you need to implement a [FILTER](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html) in your web app and configure it to accept or reject requests based on their remote address IP. Remote address can be retrieved from `ServletRequest` object passed into `doFilter` method.

You declare a filter in your web.xml file:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>GatekeeperFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>your.package.GatekeeperFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>allowedNetwork</param-name>
    <param-value>192\.168\.2\.*</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>GatekeeperFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/path/to/protected/folder</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Read the linked article about what need to be done to accept init parameters.  I think for your decision making you can shamelessly copy the code from the RequestDumperValve.

Comment: first thx for the quick answer, (+1). sadly this seems not to work yet. so far there's been no context section within my server.xml. Actually the application itself should be world accessible. only one folder in there, basically a folder containing some pdf's should only be accessible by certain IPs. within the app there's a simple a href link to that folder. if the client is from my internal net everything is ok. if the client is external the folder should not be openend for him. is my approach still right?

Answer (score 4):

You need to put it in the `<Context>` element which definies the webapplication in question.

For Tomcat it can be several places, under each the webapp-specific (and webapp-controlled) `/META-INF/context.xml` or the server-specific (and server-controlled) `/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/context.xml` or the server-specific global `/conf/context.xml` or the host-specific `/conf/server.xml`. Also see the [Tomcat Context documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html).

Answer (score 4):

The Tomcat Valve can be applied to the whole Engine, the Host or a specific Context (webapp). You have to use it for you whole app, not specific path or directories.

You should set it in your META-INF/context.xml or your context fragment in conf/Catalina/[host] directory. For example,

```
<Context path="/myapp" ...>
  ...
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="10.1.2.*"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: Helpful.  I'm able to restrict my site to the proper IPv4 block by doing that.  However, it doesn't seem to work for IPv6.  Is there a different way to do that, or does Tomcat still not have full IPv6 support?

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch, tomcat *does* support IPv6, see [prevent-access-to-certain-webapps-in-tomcat6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149719/prevent-access-to-certain-webapps-in-tomcat6)

Comment: Looks like it needs a custom build of Tomcat to support IPv6 (pre-built binaries don't seem to support it).  So far unable to find the right combination of dependencies/options to do a full build of Tomcat with working IPv6.  So, yes it supports it, but good luck actually getting it going.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Had the same need as you (but for other reasons) last week and created a valve to block requests by path. It's based off of `org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve`.

Usage:

`<Valve className="se.qbranch.tomcat.valve.BlockAccessByPathValve" path="/manager/.*" allow="127\.0\.0\.1"/>`

The valve can be used in Engine, Host or Context just as any valve and is available on GitHub. http://github.com/xlson/tomcat-valves

I would suggest using the default tomcat valves or servlet filters in your application if that solves your problem. The reason we needed a custom valve was that some parts of the tomcat management application [Psi-Probe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) would "leak out" even though we used the `RemoteAddrValve` in the `<Context>` element of the application.