# How to allow access to certain computers?

Tags: tomcat

Is there any way I could provide access depending on the `computer name` . How do I specify this condition in the `configuration` ?

Also, is there any way to grant access depending on user id (environment variable) . I used to do this using VBA . However, since this is native microsoft product i had to simply sprecify `environ` . What about tomcat ?

I read this [article](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter)  but did not quite get it . I presume I need to use `Remote Address Filter` but I need to have a example code .

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839618/tomcat-valve-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Point, Filtering requests based on the DNS hostname is "expensive". It forces tomcat to do a reverse DNS lookup. When the request comes up it does not comes with a DNS name, but just the IP address of client. So tomcat has to ask the system for name (or names) that corresponds to client's IP address.

If you want to accept request from specific host name, you might already know the IP address (or range of IP addresses) that correspond to the hostname. If so then you can use `Remote Address Filter` to set the required value (IP addresses) to it.

Second Point, Using `Remote Address Filter` gives a flexibility with two attributes, `allow` and `deny`.

**Example:**

**NOTE**: The IP addresses used here are just to show as example.

Suppose there is a hostname `myhostname` with IP address range `134.87.13.0 - 134.87.13.255`.
You want to allow only this range and deny all others.
You would do a DNS lookup for this range. Say If you find it as `164.32.90.100`.

Then you would configure your Valve as:

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="164\.32\.90\.100, 134\.87\.13\.\d{1,3}" />
```

Now suppose that within the range, you want to deny a subrange `134.87.13.51 - 134.87.13.60`.

Then you would configure your Valve as:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="164\.32\.90\.100, 134\.87\.13\.\d{1,3}" deny="134\.87\.13\.(5[1-9]|60)" />
```

Configuring dynamic values for `allow` and `deny` is possible using regular expression.

Might these details help you to solve your issue.

**Edited**

One Final Point, If you allow / deny range of IP addresses, you must not deny the request from "localhost". So add `127\.0\.0\.1` to your allow range.